# How can I convert code to a string or print it with proper spaces in scheme?

Tags: debugging, macros, lisp, scheme

Is there a way to convert code to a string in scheme with proper spaces or even pretty print?

So when I apply this to a form like (+ 1 2) it should result in "(+ 1 2)" and not in "+12".

Comment: Should work on all schemes !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try quoting the expression, that should be enough for displaying it, and it'll be easier to manipulate (easier than manipulating a string):

```
(display '(+ 1 2))
=> '(+ 1 2)  ; a quoted expression
```

Or if you definitely need a string, in Racket you can do something like this - but once again, the expression has to be quoted first:

```
(format "~a" '(+ 1 2))
=> "(+ 1 2)" ; a string
```

Yet another way, using a string output port:

```
(define o (open-output-string))
(write '(+ 1 2) o)
(get-output-string o)
(close-output-port o)
=> "(+ 1 2)" ; a string
```

Finally, an example using Racket's [pretty printing](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pretty-print.html) library:

```
(require racket/pretty)
(define o (open-output-string))
(pretty-write '(+ 1 2) o)
(get-output-string o)
(close-output-port o)
=> "(+ 1 2)\n" ; a formatted string
```

Answer (score 4):

In guile, you can:

```
(use-modules (ice-9 pretty-print))
(pretty-print value output-port)
```

Where `expr` is any value and `output-port` is any port (such as a string port if you want to capture the output as a string)